# Accessing Magento admin cookie in a custom file inside a folder

Tags: magento-1.8, admin, session

I have a magento installation I want to access the logged in admin credentials in a file inside a subfolder.
I make a file and keep it in the root (the same folder where the magento index.php resides). It shows me the logged in user data perfectly. Now when I copy the same file inside a subfolder it returns the data but the data array(which contains the loggedin user information) is empty. Below is the code

> require_once ('app/Mage.php');
>
> Mage::app();
>
> $user = Mage::getSingleton('admin/session');
>
> print_r($user);

Answer (score 0):

The proper way to get the current logged in admin user in a sub folder is as below.

```
require_once ('../app/Mage.php');
$admin = Mage::getSingleton('admin/session')->getUser();
```

As the custom file is in a sub folder at the root of the magento, so you have to include `Mage.php` properly as mentioned in above code.

Now you can fetch different admin properties as below:

```
$admin->getId(); //Get ID
$admin->getUserName() //Get user name
```

Hope this helps.

Thank you

Comment: The same issue the code you provided works in the file that is in the root. But inside php file in the folder when I paste this it says Call to a member function getId() on a non-object